# Able to change a string in js and read it back but can't write back to the js file

Tags: python

I tried to update the second line "app_version_1 = 'app.0111'; to "app_version_1 = 'app.0112';".  I open the file and file the specify line, modify the line and read it to make sure the 2nd line is change.  Then I tried to use write() to write is back to the text file but it didn't work.

**Sample text file**:

```
    app_version_0 = 'app.0111';
    app_version_1 = 'app.0111';
    app_version_2 = 'app.0113';
```

**Here is the code**:

```
def edit_appversion():
    with open('test_file.js', 'r') as rf:
        with open('test_file.js', 'w') as wf:
            listme = rf.readlines()
            listme[1] = "app_version_1 = 'app.0112';"
            print(listme)
            wf = rf.writelines(listme)
            wf.close()

def main()
    edit_appversion()
```

Comment: And if I run it.  It emptyed out the text file.

Comment: Do you call `main()`? How do you know it didn't work?

Comment: `open('test_file.js', 'w')` will delete the contents of an existing file.

Comment: You're calling ``writelines()`` on ``rf``, not ``wf``!